# How to download Google Compute Engine disk content?

Tags: neo4j, google-compute-engine, kubernetes, persistent-storage

I have linked a Persistent Volume to my Kubernetes Neo4j Replication Controller to store the DB data. Now I would like to download that data locally to run the production DB on my system. I can't find the way to download the Disk content. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Updates (Persistent Volume Creation with Kubernetes):

```
persistent-volume-db.json
{
  "kind": "PersistentVolume",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "pv-db"
  },
  "spec": {
    "capacity": {
      "storage": "500Gi"
    },
    "accessModes": [
      "ReadWriteMany"
    ],
    "gcePersistentDisk": {
      "pdName": "tuwa-db-data-disk",
      "fsType": "ext4"
    }
  }
}

persistent-volume-claim-db.json
{
  "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "pvc"
  },
  "spec": {
    "accessModes": [
      "ReadWriteMany"
    ],
    "resources": {
      "requests": {
        "storage": "500Gi"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then the usage:

```
neo4j-controller.json
{
  "kind": "ReplicationController",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "neo4j-controller",
    "labels": {
      "name": "neo4j"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "name": "neo4j"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "neo4j",
            "image": "neo4j/neo4j",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "neo4j-server",
                "containerPort": 7474
              }
            ],
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "mountPath": "/data/databases",
                "name": "pv-db"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "pv-db",
            "persistentVolumeClaim": {
              "claimName": "pvc-db"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCE's admin panel doesn't have a "download" button for persistent disks, but `gcloud` makes it easy to copy files from an instance to your local machine:

`gcloud compute copy-files example-instance:~/REMOTE-DIR ~/LOCAL-DIR --zone us-central1-a`

This will copy `~/REMOTE-DIR` from a remote instance into `~/LOCAL-DIR` on your machine. Just replace the directory names, `example-instance` with your instances name, and adjust your zone if necessary. More info here in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/copy-files).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it seems that the disk is not an instance and so you can't connect to it. Or am my misunderstanding some thing ? I have instances running my Kubernetes setup and disks associated to some pods. I want to access those Persistent Volume, I can see them in the console but I can't access them with gcloud compute ssh <instance-name> as they are not instances.

Comment: Correct, the disks won't be instances, but your instances will have _mounted_ the persistent disk if its pods are using it. It depends on how they're mounted, but you should ssh into your instance (which you can also do via `gcloud`) and look in `/mnt` or `/dev/disk/by-id/`. You'll probably find the disks there. Once you find the where the PD is mounted in your instance, you can use `gcloud compute copy-files`.

Comment: Thanks that was a big hep me ;)

Comment: I have found in /dev/disk/by-id/ this:
google-persistent-disk-0        
google-tuwa-data-disk     
scsi-google-persistent-disk-0         
scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_persistent-disk-0       
... 
At the risk of asking a dumb question, none of those files is a folder, what are they? They have the name of my PD though.

Comment: If you run `file` on those two files, they're probably pointing to `/dev/sda1` or something similar. It depends on a number of factors in your cluster, but they may be disks that are attached to your instance but not mounted. You can mount them manually with `sudo mkdir /mnt/YOUR_FOLDER` and `sudo mount /dev/disk/by-id/DISK_NAME /mnt/YOUR_FOLDER`.

Comment: Yes with file I got ```google-tuwa-db-data-disk: symbolic link to `../../sdb'``` and others pointing to sda1, sdc...
But the folders 2 dir above doesn't exist. I would think that my drive is mounted (somewhere) as I am persisting my application data when I restart the Replication Controller. I will update my question with how I created my Drive.

Comment: I mounted the drive on my node and now I can copy my remote dada. Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
gcloud compute copy-files  #has been deprecated
```

Please use `gcloud compute scp` instead.  Note that `gcloud compute scp` does not have recursive copy on by default.  To turn on recursion, use the `--recurse` flag.

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse example-instance:~/instance-1_path  ~/locad_path --zone=us-central1-a
```

This will copy ~/instance-1_path from a remote compute instance into ~/local_path on your personal machine. Just replace the directory names, example-instance with your instances name, and adjust your zone if necessary.

Complete documentation of this SDK can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp)